# How to UPDATE a table on SQL Server with multiple Joins on the updated table? (FROM FROM JOIN)

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update

How to UPDATE a table on SQL Server with multiple Joins on the updated table? 
In MySQL you can define a Alias for updated table, but how does it works with TSQL.

```
 UPDATE recert.ou              --#1-- In MSSQL/TSQL no alias allowed
SET parent_id = o2.ID
    FROM recert.ou as O              
    JOIN recert.country C ON C.ID = O.country_id
    JOIN recert.ou P ON O.parent_id = P.ID and p.country_id <> O.country_id     
    JOIN recert.ou o2 on o2.name = p.name and c.ID = o2.country_id              
    JOIN recert.country as c2 on c2.ID = o2.country_id
           WHERE O.ID = o2.ID
```

-

```
RESULT: *The table 'o' is ambiguous.*
```

Comment: Why would you alias `o` as `o`?

Comment: What happens if you have `UPDATE O1 SET parent_id = O2.ID FROM o AS O1 blah blah blah...`? TSQL *does* allow an alias to appear in the `UPDATE` statement. But I've never tried aliasing a table to it's own name before.

Comment: @NikolaMarkovinović: Original: `FROM recert.o AS o`

Comment: What version of Sql Server? I've just checked against 2005 and yes, you can use alias in update statement.

Comment: SQL Server 2008 R2: `Msg 8154, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
The table 'recert.o' is ambiguous.` Its because the `JOIN recert.o P`and `JOIN recert.o o2`.

Comment: @NikolaMarkovinović : Since he is joining with the same table alias will give an error .Doing an inner join with the same table will throw an error ambiguous table .You can use alias with an update statement if you are not joining with the same table which is getting updated  in the query  .

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[This works on Sql Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c19eb/3).

```
UPDATE o
SET parent_id = o2.ID
    FROM recert O
    JOIN c C ON C.ID = O.country_id
    JOIN recert P ON O.parent_id = P.ID and p.country_id <> O.country_id
    JOIN recert o2 on o2.name = p.name and c.ID = o2.country_id
    JOIN c c2 on c2.ID = o2.country_id
WHERE O.ID = o2.ID
```

I suppose the problem arose because you tried to re-alias an alias, but I'm not sure.

Comment: `recert` is the shema and the table is `ou`. -> `recert.ou as o`. I edit the question.

Comment: @hoerf - think of this as a proof of concept. Just add .ou to each recert in the query above.

Comment: @hoerf As your query stands now, replace `update recert.ou` with `update o`

Comment: its the same like in my quetstion

Comment: @hoerf The point was to use alias in update, and you are using table name.

Answer (score 1):

You can move everything into the WHERE clause:

```
UPDATE o              --#1-- In MSSQL/TSQL no alias allowed
    SET parent_id = o2.ID
    FROM c, o, o o2, C c2
    Where o.country_id = c.id and o.parent_id = p.id and p.country_id <> O.country_id and
          o2.name = p.name and c.ID = o2.country_id and c2.ID = o2.country_id
```

This is *not* my favorite style of joins, but it should suffice for your purposes.

However, in TSQL, I would really do the following.  Create a query that returns the new update value for each id.  Then write a query with the following format:

```
with toupdate as (<the query>)
    update o
        set o.parent_id = toupdate.id
    from toupdate
    where o.id = toupdate.id
```

Comment: SAME ERROR `UPDATE recert.ou SET parent_id = o2.[ID] FROM recert.ou AS O, recert.country, recert.ou AS P, recert.ou as o2, recert.country c2, recert.country c WHERE O.ID = o2.ID AND C.ID = O.country_id AND O.parent_id = P.ID and p.country_id <> O.country_id AND o2.name = p.name and c.ID = o2.country_id AND c2.ID = o2.country_id `

Answer (score 1):

You just need to remove the alias name for o table

```
UPDATE o              
SET parent_id = o2.ID
FROM o               
JOIN c C ON C.ID = o.country_id
JOIN o P ON o.parent_id = P.ID and p.country_id <> o.country_id   
JOIN o o2 on o2.name = p.name and c.ID = o2.country_id             
JOIN c c2 on c2.ID = o2.country_id
 WHERE o.ID = o2.ID
```

Comment: Original: `FROM recert.o AS O` I use `o` as alias in the `JOIN ... o.country_id`

Answer (score -2):

self joined update

```
update #table1 set column1= b.column2
from #table1 #table1, #table1 b where #table1.Id=b.Id
```

Comment: Replace #table1 with the actual table name. column1 with the actual column name and column2 with the actual column name